# STUFF doesn't work well with NULL Values and Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with below schema and data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SearchTest]
(
    [DocumentNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AlphaNumeric] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Integers] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[SearchTest] ([DocumentNumber], [AlphaNumeric], [Integers]) 
VALUES (1, N'abc', 1)

INSERT [dbo].[SearchTest] ([DocumentNumber], [AlphaNumeric], [Integers]) 
VALUES (2, N'abc', 1)

INSERT [dbo].[SearchTest] ([DocumentNumber], [AlphaNumeric], [Integers]) 
VALUES (3, N'bcd', 2)

INSERT [dbo].[SearchTest] ([DocumentNumber], [AlphaNumeric], [Integers]) 
VALUES (4, N'bcd', 2)
GO
```

Table data:

[image: SearchTest]

I would like to do grouping using `Alphanumeric` and `Integers` column and get the `DocumentNumber` as comma separated value in my final result.

My final result should look like this,

[image: Final Result]

Here is my query that gives the above output,

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT
         STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()] 
                FROM SearchTest 
                WHERE AlphaNumeric = Result.Alphanumeric 
                   OR Integers = Result.Integers 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ' ') DocumentNumbers, 
        COUNT(DocumentNumber) TotalDocuments, 
        Result.AlphaNumeric, 
        Result.Integers 
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM SearchTest 
         WHERE AlphaNumeric LIKE '%b%' OR Integers = 1) AS Result 
    GROUP BY 
        Result.AlphaNumeric, Result.Integers) AS Final
```

However the above query breaks if I have null values in `Integers` column.

For example, if I have `NULL` value in my integer columns as shown here:

[image: Search Test With NULL Values]

Now my query breaks and I get the wrong results in my stuff query as shown below

[image]

Grouping works fine in the above query but `STUFF` part which gives `DocumentNumbers` gives wrong result. In this case it has be `2` in first row and `1` in second row.

Here is the expected result:

```
| DocumentNumbers| TotalDocuments| AlphaNumeric  | Integers      |
+----------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| 2              | 1             | abc           | NULL          |
| 1              | 1             | abc           | 1             |
| 3, 4           | 2             | bcd           | 2             |
```

Please assist on where I'm going wrong

Comment: That's not a problem with `STUFF` at all. `NULL + {any value} = NULL`. If you have `NULL` values handle them by either omitting them in your `WHERE` (`ColumnName IS NOT NULL`) or replace the `NULL` value with `ISNULL`/`COALESCE`. Or perhaps instead of using the concatenation operator (`+`) use `CONCAT`, which does not return `NULL` if any of the expressions have the value `NULL`.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you DO want.  Also, I would recommend creating a DB/SQL Fiddle.  And explain why you are not using `string_agg()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I have added the expected result. I'm not aware of `string_agg()`.

Comment: [`STRING_AGG`] was introduced in SQL Server 2017, @fingers10 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @GordonLinoff comments in the question. This can be easily achieved using `STRING_AGG()` provided you're using `SQL Server 2017` and above. This simplifies the query as well.

**Query:**

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        STRING_AGG(Result.DocumentNumber, ', ') DocumentNumbers, 
        COUNT(DocumentNumber) TotalDocuments, 
        Result.AlphaNumeric, 
        Result.Integers
    FROM
        (SELECT * 
         FROM SearchTest 
         WHERE AlphaNumeric LIKE '%b%' OR Integers = 1) AS Result 
    GROUP BY 
        Result.AlphaNumeric, Result.Integers) AS Final
```

**Expected Output:**

[image: Answer]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `WHERE` clause of the inner query to a) use `AND` instead of `OR` and b) to check for `NULL`s too.

```
SELECT stuff((SELECT concat(', ', documentnumber)
                     FROM searchtest st2
                     WHERE (st2.alphanumeric = st1.alphanumeric
                             OR st2.alphanumeric IS NULL
                                AND st1.alphanumeric IS NULL)
                           AND (st2.integers = st1.integers
                                 OR st2.integers IS NULL
                                    AND st1.integers IS NULL)
                     FOR XML PATH('')),
             1,
             2,
             '') documentnumbers,
      count(*) totaldocuments,
      alphanumeric,
      integers
      FROM searchtest st1
      WHERE st1.alphanumeric LIKE '%b%'
             OR st1.integers = 1
      GROUP BY st1.alphanumeric,
               st1.integers;
```

Answer (score -1):

I had edited the code now:

You can use the below code to attain this:

```
SELECT S.DocumentNumbers,COUNT(S.DocumentNumbers) AS TotalDocuments,S.AlphaNumeric,S.Integers FROM
(SELECT COALESCE(Stuff((SELECT ', ' + CAST(DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) 
        FROM SearchTest T1
        WHERE T1.AlphaNumeric=T2.AlphaNumeric AND T1.Integers=T2.Integers
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ')
        ,CAST (T2.DocumentNumber AS VARCHAR(20))) AS DocumentNumbers,T2.AlphaNumeric,T2.Integers
FROM SearchTest T2) S
GROUP BY DocumentNumbers,S.AlphaNumeric,S.Integers
ORDER BY S.Integers
```

[image]

Comment: I had Edited the Code.Can u Check now - @fingers10

Comment: Did u Checked this? --@fingers10